# ESLint and StyleLint setup in PhpStorm for Shopware 6

Tags: phpstorm, eslint, shopware6, stylelint

I'm searching for a tutorial/help to setup **ESLint** and **Stylelint** in **PhpStorm** for **Shopware 6** to use the Shopware linters. I did not found helpful documentations in the official Shopware docs.

I found 2 Shopware ESLint configurations in `/vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/eslintrc.js` for storefront and `/vendor/shopware/administration/Resources/app/administration/.eslintrc.js` for administration?!

I was using this docs: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/eslint.html
and was ready to configure ESLint in the PhpStorm settings...

How can I use the correct linter configurations for administration and storefront files in a custom/plugin etc.?

**How do you set this up correctly?**

[image]

And I got this error:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the "Automatic" option? With the default (automatic) configuration, WebStorm uses the .eslintrc.* configuration nearest to the current file, traversing the folders structure up to the project root. If it doesn't work, it might be worth reporting the issue in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB.

Comment: I haven't really tried "Automatic" because I think "nearest" won't work since the linter configurations are in the vendor folder and the work-sources are under a parallel directory, example:

working sources: ROOT/custom/plugins/plugin-xyz | 
linter configurations: ROOT/vendor/shopware/.../.eslintrc.js